# Inplace union sorted vectors

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, vector, stdvector

I'd like an efficient method for doing the **inplace** union of a sorted vector with another sorted vector.  By inplace, I mean that the algorithm shouldn't create a whole new vector or other storage to store the union, even temporarily.  Instead, the first vector should simple grow by exactly the number of new elements.

Something like:

```
void inplace_union(vector & A, const vector & B);
```

Where, afterwards, **A** contains all of the elements of **A** union **B** *and* is sorted.

`std::set_union` in `<algorithm>` wont work because it overwrites its destination, which would be **A**.

Also, can this be done with just one pass over the two vectors?

Edit: elements that are in **both** A **and** B should only appear once in A.

Answer (score 6):

I believe you can use the algorithm `std::inplace_merge`. Here is the sample code:

```
void inplace_union(std::vector<int>& a, const std::vector<int>& b)
{
    int mid = a.size(); //Store the end of first sorted range

    //First copy the second sorted range into the destination vector
    std::copy(b.begin(), b.end(), std::back_inserter(a));

    //Then perform the in place merge on the two sub-sorted ranges.
    std::inplace_merge(a.begin(), a.begin() + mid, a.end());

    //Remove duplicate elements from the sorted vector
    a.erase(std::unique(a.begin(), a.end()), a.end());
}
```

Comment: A union of sets implies that the result set does not have the same element in it twice... right?

Comment: Yes.. as you can not have duplicate elements in a set. But in this case since we are sorted vectors the duplicates are allowed, however I am not sure whether the relative position of the similar objects is preserved in `inplace_merge` i.e. whether it is *stable* or not.

Comment: You can remove the duplicates, if applicable, with `std::unique`

Comment: I am not worried about stability.

Comment: Replacing `std::copy` with `std::set_difference` would remove the need for `std::unique`.

Comment: @user438601: That's why I am not storing an iterator to the end. I am just storing an index to the end. `mid` is a simple `int` not an `iterator`

Comment: Right, my bad.  And since vectors have random access iterators, the + mid is O(1), so I think you've got it if you change to `std::set_difference`.

Comment: Are you sure? `std::set_difference` would not only remove the duplicates, but the first instance too! (the difference of `[1, 2, 3]` and `[1, 2, 3]` is `[]`) *Edit:* Actually, I think I'm probably wrong here...

Comment: Yeah, I am wrong. You want to copy B, minus the elements in A, or B - A, which is what `set_difference` does.

Comment: @Naveen: Does this solution meet the requirement " Instead, the first vector should simple grow by exactly the number of new elements.". In this solution, we created more space and then removed duplicates.

Comment: @chubsdad: Right now no, the requirement for having the unique elements was added later. Before that requirement, that condition was satisfied.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done in-place, and in O(*n*) time, assuming both inputs are sorted, and with one pass over both vectors. Here's how:

Extend `A` (the destination vector) by `B.size()` - make room for our new elements.

Iterate backwards over the two vectors, starting from the end of `B` and the original end of `A`. If the vectors are sorted small → big (big at the end), then take the iterator pointing at the larger number, and stick it in the true end of `A`. Keep going until `B`'s iterator hits the beginning of `B`. Reverse iterators should prove especially nice here.

Example:

```
A: [ 1, 2, 4, 9 ]
B: [ 3, 7, 11 ]

* = iterator, ^ = where we're inserting, _ = unitialized
A: [ 1, 3, 4, 9*, _, _, _^ ]   B: [ 3, 7, 11* ]
A: [ 1, 3, 4, 9*, _, _^, 11 ]  B: [ 3, 7*, 11 ]
A: [ 1, 3, 4*, 9, _^, 9, 11 ]  B: [ 3, 7*, 11 ]
A: [ 1, 3, 4*, 9^, 7, 9, 11 ]  B: [ 3*, 7, 11 ]
A: [ 1, 3*, 4^, 4, 7, 9, 11 ]  B: [ 3*, 7, 11 ]
A: [ 1, 3*^, 3, 4, 7, 9, 11 ]  B: [ 3, 7, 11 ]
```

**Super edit:** Have you considered `std::inplace_merge`? (which I may have just re-invented?)

Comment: A union of sets implies that the result set does not have the same element in it twice... right?  You just posted the merge algorithm that is the basis for merge sort.

Comment: You're answer is closer than I thought.  If you have a check for the same element being in both (skipping it), you'd be done... except for now you don't know how much longer to make A.

Comment: The original post talked of a union of vectors. `std::unique` can fix this after a merge. I would still go with `std::inplace_merge` -- it seems to do exactly what my post does, and combined with `std::unique`, exactly what you want, minus all the hard work.

Comment: Yes, but then we have used extra memory expanding A to the size of A plus B (when maybe it can be much smaller), and extra work copying elements from B that are already in A (could be a lot).

Comment: @user428601: You would then have to modify my above algorithm to do an initial pass over A & B to count duplicates, and to not add those spaces. (And then be careful to not copy them.) Significantly complicates things, so unless you need it, I'd still go with the STL version.

Answer (score 0):

The `set_difference` idea is good, but the disadvantage is we don't know how much we need to grow the vector in advance.

This is my solution which does the `set_difference` twice, once to count the number of extra slots we'll need, and once again to do the actual copy.

Note: that means we will iterate over the source twice.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/function_output_iterator.hpp>

// for the test
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>


struct output_counter
{
   output_counter(size_t & r) : result(r) {}
   template <class T> void operator()(const T & x) const { ++result; }
private:
   size_t & result;
};


// Target is assumed to work the same as a vector
// Both target and source must be sorted
template <class Target, class It>
void inplace_union( Target & target, It src_begin, It src_end )
{
   const size_t mid = target.size(); // Store the end of first sorted range

   // first, count how many items we will copy
   size_t extra = 0;
   std::set_difference( 
         src_begin, src_end,
         target.begin(), target.end(),
         boost::make_function_output_iterator(output_counter(extra)));

   if (extra > 0) // don't waste time if nothing to do
   {
      // reserve the exact memory we will require
      target.reserve( target.size() + extra );

      // Copy the items from the source that are missing in the destination
      std::set_difference( 
            src_begin, src_end,
            target.begin(), target.end(),
            std::back_inserter(target) );

      // Then perform the in place merge on the two sub-sorted ranges.
      std::inplace_merge( target.begin(), target.begin() + mid, target.end() );
   }
}



int main()
{
   std::vector<int> a(3), b(3);
   a[0] = 1;
   a[1] = 3;
   a[2] = 5;

   b[0] = 4;
   b[1] = 5;
   b[2] = 6;

   inplace_union(a, b.begin(), b.end());

   for (size_t i = 0; i != a.size(); ++i)
      std::cout << a[i] << ", ";
   std::cout << std::endl;

   return 0;
}
```

Compiled with the boost headers, the result is:

```
$ ./test 
1, 3, 4, 5, 6,
```